# Is it possible to embedd an X window inside a web frame?

Tags: apache, frame, x11

we have different kinds of monitoring software, each one has its own pourpose and none of the can do all the monitoring by itself.

I was trying to centralize all four platforms on a single web site, so it will be easy to check all monitors faster and easier.

2 of the monitoring services have a linux X console, and can be exported as through ssh -X.

The other two have web interface, so it should be easy to embedd.

Does anyone know how I can embedd this Xwindows on a web iframe? As an example I could say that I want to embedd xclock on a web frame. Is it possible?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture portion of X11 display and stream it with **`ffmpeg`** using `x11grab` command and video streaming server.

See:

- [**x11grab**](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC29)
- [**ffserver**](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffserver.html)